# Spring Cloud Camden.SR4 with Spring Boot 1.5.1?

Tags: spring-cloud

I am wanting to upgrade our platform to the latest official release of spring boot. I would like to move to 1.5.1, but I want to make sure its compatible with Spring Cloud Camden.SR4?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Response from Spring (Opened on Spring Cloud Sleuth issues):

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/issues/508

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, we are currently not using Sleuth, but the comment from Marcin is encouraging:  "The upcoming release of Camden will provide support for Boot 1.5."

Answer (score 3):

It might depend on which libraries you use within Spring Cloud.

One issue is that in Spring Boot 1.5.1 they removed the `org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletRegistrationBean` (marked as `@Depricated` as of 1.4) in favour to `org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean`.

It will be a problem if you are e.g. using Zuul? Zuul's autoconfiguration is relying on `org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletRegistrationBean` (in Camden.SR4) and I can assume that other libraries under Spring Cloud could do the same.

Comment: We are using Zuul and I ran into this exact issue. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @Tyler Spring Cloud Camden SR5 is released now with Spring Boot 1.5.1 compatibility :)
https://spring.io/blog/2017/02/06/spring-cloud-camden-sr5-is-available

Comment: Also note other issues: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/1663

Comment: For Reference, I am still running into a couple of issues with Camden.SR5 + Spring Boot 1.5.1 and the Spring Cloud Stream Kafka binder. I have opened up a second question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42079585/configuring-spring-cloud-stream-in-camden-sr5-with-spring-boot-1-5-1