# Configuring Spring Cloud Stream in Camden.SR5 with Spring boot 1.5.1

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

First off, thanks to the Spring team for all their work pushing this work forward!

Now that Camden.SR5 is official, I have some questions on how to correctly configure the spring cloud stream kafka binder when using Spring Boot 1.5.1.

Spring boot 1.5.1 has auto configuration for kafka and those configuration options seem to be redundant with those in the spring cloud stream kafka binder.

Do we use the core spring boot properties (spring.kafka.*) or do we use (spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.*)?

I did find this issue, but I am curious if this work will be included in the next Camden release?

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues/73

Additionally, I saw this issue reported on Stack Overflow and I believe it will also be an issue with Camden.SR5?

[Failed to start bean 'inputBindingLifecycle' when using spring-boot:1.5.1 and spring-cloud-stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41986162/failed-to-start-bean-inputbindinglifecycle-when-using-spring-boot1-5-1-and-sp)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supporting the Boot 1.5 configuration options is an issue in progress. Also, since dedicated 1.5 support is coming only with Spring Cloud Stream Chelsea release train (which is included in the Dalston release of Spring Cloud), it will be available only there.

Also, when using Spring Cloud Camden with Boot 1.5 you will need to override the Kafka dependencies as described in [Failed to start bean 'inputBindingLifecycle' when using spring-boot:1.5.1 and spring-cloud-stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41986162/failed-to-start-bean-inputbindinglifecycle-when-using-spring-boot1-5-1-and-sp). This will be avoided in future versions of Spring Cloud Stream (and Spring Cloud) but only starting in the Chelsea release train of Spring Cloud Stream (and the Dalston release of Spring Cloud) - see https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues/88 for details.

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback.